# Is it possible to deploy computer based GPO's over VPN connection?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

Brand new domain, right now only have one DC (2012 r2) which is offsite.  I have a number of laptops that I want to join to the domain over VPN (that part has been successful), and then apply computer based GPO's to install various pieces of software to each laptop.  The laptops connect to the domain via Cisco VPN client, and are all running Windows 10 Pro.

I know computer based GPO software installs are applied at computer startup, is there no way that the machine can download the GPO once connected, and then apply it when it is restarted - so far I haven't found anything useful via Google.

Just trying to figure out if I should just keep testing this, or abandon and just install the software manually (moving forward this is not a great solution).  Ideally we'd have a solution for when the company grows and brings on new employees and computers (all remote), and we can just send them laptops with the VPN software pre-installed and allow them to log in and have the policies and software package installs applied without us having to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to wait for two client OS restarts you could try the following:

1. Deploy the file to the local client via Group Policy Preferences.
2. Install the package via Group Policy but specify the new local client location.
3. Wait for two client restarts.